# I would like to know the formula for calculating force on a 90 degree bent second class lever arm as shown in attached figure

Tags: mechanical-engineering

What is the formula to calculate force F2 given L1, L2, L3 and F1?
(updated: wrong question asked. originally it said: "What is the formula to calculate force F1 given L1, L2, L3 and F2?
Now question is correct...bahhh, question was correct in the attached sketch though)

The angle in red lever arm is 90 degree.
Please see attached image.[image: Image showing bent second class lever arm]

### update

Thanks to r13 for an updated answer. I still do not how that formula is correct (I do not say I know it is wrong, but I do believe it is wrong. According to r13 last formula I end up with this: F2=2(F1*L1)/L3, which again is not using distance L2 - which I definitely belive will affect F2). I need to understand better how the correct formula is beeing set up, so I know what I'm doing. Please look at my second sketch added in this comment, and also see the text and question(s) in the sketch. I believe it is possible to simplify the the bent second class red lever to another lever (see new sketch), and that it is easier to set up (and understand - for me) the formula(s) used, to calculate F2.
[image]

Comment: Show what you have done to solve this. Perhaps start here: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/levers-d_1304.html#gsc.tab=0

Comment: Thanks for that, but I have allready looked at formulas for those setups... but do not know how to make a formula for the kind of lever arm in the figure I posted. So I was hoping that someone with a better understanding of this, could help me out.

Comment: I have allready looked at formula for a second class lever arm (see link below)... but do not know how to make a formula for the the bent second class lever arm in the figure I posted. So I was hoping that someone with a better understanding of this, could help me out. 
https://www.firgelliauto.com/blogs/news/calculator-for-a-second-class-lever#:~:text=In%20this%20case%2C%20the%20formula,being%20moved%20by%20the%20lever 

I do not want to guess the formula to use, so I was hoping for some help for the formula.

Answer (score 1):

The tendency to rotate about the hinge point must be kept at "zero".

$\sum M_{hinge} = 0$

$F_1*L_1 - F_2*L_3 = 0$

$F_2 = F_1*(L_1/L_3)$

**Moment (M):**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that answer. But how can you skip using L2 (ref. my figure) in the formula? Could you please explain?

Comment: The tendency to rotate (called the "moment") about the support is the product of force and its lateral distance measured to the support point. Here, you have two tendencies - F1*L1 and F2*L3, and L1 & L3 are the lever arms between the forces and the support hinge. If you have a vertical downward force on the vertical leg, then you will have one more tendency to rotate - F*(L1+L2), in the same direction as F1*L1.

Comment: I still believe one must use the L2 in the formula
Example
a: L1 = 1, L2 = 1. Gives the horisontal lever part is 2. 
Which again mean that at the right point of horsontal lever part has a force down on:  MA = L/E = 1/2. If F1 = 100kg then that force is 50kg. 
B) If you change L2 to say 9, then the downward force on the bottom right part of the lever is: MA = 1/10 which gives 10 kg. If lever has no mass and hinge has no friction, it looks to me that the force F2 in example 2 here, is much less than in the first example, if L3 is same for both examples. How can L2 be removed in the formula?

Comment: You need to review how the lever arm is measured - from the line of action (the force) **measured perpendicularly** to the support point. L2 will be in the equation only if there is a force acting up/down the vertical leg.

Comment: I think my last example above here, did show that there is a force acting down on the vertical leg of the 90 degree lever in the figure in thread start. I also showed how I could calculate that force using the formula for a second class lever (where the forces are 90 degree on the lever (here the horisontal part of the bent lever). If a force F1 pulling down L1 away from the hinge, there must be a force pulling down the vertical part of the lever L1 + L2 away from the hinge. In my previous example the downward force (on the vertical part of lever) differs if L2 change and L1 and L3 is the same

Comment: Added one more sketch for you to review. If you can't get it, sorry, I gave up.

Comment: Please: note the direction of F2 (see the arrow in the example figure in thread start) . F2 is pushing horisontally on top of the vertical part of the lever - to the left.

Comment: Using your new formula where you include L2:
M = F2 * L3 - F3 * (L1 + L2) - F1 * L2

Since: F3 = (L1 / L1 + L2) * F1

Then I believe we get (from the formula you used): 
F2 = (L1 * F1 - L2 * F1) / L3

which is different from what your first formula (unless I'm mistaken here), which says
F2 = F1 * L1/L3 

So which of the two formulas do you mean are correct?

Wil now try attack the problem in two steps. First calculate F3 ref. your sketch (as an upward force). Then calculate F2 based on a lever going directly from the hinge and through point on L3 where force arrow F2 meets L3

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake on the last sketch. See the updated. Now, if F3 = 0, which was your original case, what will happen?

Comment: Ooops... I saw I had som wrong text initially in original question, which originally said: "What is the formula to calculate force F1 given L1, L2, L3 and F2?"
That is wrong: It should be: "What is the formula to calculate force F2 given L1, L2, L3 and F1?"
It is now corrected in thread start post. Sorry for the "bug".

Comment: My original solution stands correct. For the bracket to remain stable, M1 must equal to M2 (means M1 and M2 cancel each other). From there, you can calculate the magnitude of F2.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of other future users. r13's answer is correct and I upvoted it.

Trying to answer why L2 does not play a roll in this lever is that there is no orthagonal force acted on its end, the corner of the lever, in other wrds zero orthagonal force is acting at the right end of L2.

L2 could be 10 times bigger or 10 times smaller. The balance of moments is still the same.

$$\Sigma M_{hinge}=0 \quad F_1*L_1=F_2*L_3$$

It is the definition of momen of a force about a point that the moment, M,is the force vector multiplied by its distance from the point. It is unfortunate that OP has never understood this foundamental definition. However regardless of OP's belief the fact remains that
$$F_2= F_1*L_1/L_3$$

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this. Also thanks to r13 - for not giving up.